# UITableViewController custom cell disappear when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I saw a couple of questions that are similar to mine but non of them answered my question
I have a UITableview that has custom cells.

> **My view hierarchy:**
>
> **I have a main UIViewController that has a UITableViewController in it **
>   **The UITableViewController has a custom UITableViewCell**

when i load the UIViewController the cell appear perfectly but when I scroll down/up
the table gets cleared out, nothing stays there...

heres the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";
    EXCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[EXCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Post *post = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgBack.image=post.cover_img_url;
    cell.imgProf.image=post.profile_img_url;
    cell.lblValidUntil.text = post.exp_date;
    cell.lblPost.text       = post.sentence;
    cell.lblLocation.text   = post.location;

    return cell;
}
```

And here the viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EXCustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseID"];
}
```

and finally the Custom cell class

.m file:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

.h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgBack;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgProf;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblPost;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblValidUntil;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLocation;
```

I'v tried to look everywhere but couldn't find the problem.

thanks a lot

Comment: Does your view controller conform to UITableViewDataSource protocol?
And does your tableView.dataSource link to your viewController?

Comment: And, please, expand your answer by adding code from your EXCustomCell class. I want to look what do you have in your -init, -initWithFrame.
And, do you have something like EXCustomCellDelegate or EXCustomCellViewController?

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a cell (never `nil`), so you can remove the `if (cell == nil) ...`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint, and tell me what do you see happening in this method when you scroll (and before the scroll)?

Comment: @meaning-matters : when i scroll the method does not file the method.

Comment: @meaning-matters That's true for collection views but not table views.  From the Apple docs on UITableView return value for that method: 'A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or *nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.*' In this case a class is registered, so it won't return nil, but `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` does not universally always return a cell.